# c# data annotations validade Model, out of context of binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, razor-pages

I’m using asp.net core 3.1 razor pages and wanna validade a model on a upload process using data annotation.

My model is:

```
  public class UserUpload
  {
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "email must be informed"), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Maximum for name is 100 chars")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }
  }
```

Processing each line of the file uploaded how can I use data annotations to validade records and get all errors?

I have a crud for the same model and validations are processed by the framework resulting ModelState identifying all errors but I don´t know how to use the same mechanism in the mass upload data.

Tks

Comment: how should the response for multiple invalid models in one request should look like?

Comment: The upload is made by ajax, and I will show all the errors in a result area (line 1 email error and name missing, line 10 email error, etc)